# Dart Annotation - Unable to pass non constant method

Tags: dart

How can I pass-in `non-constant` method in Dart Annotations?

#### Here is my annotation:

```dart
class Injectable {
  final String name;
  final Scope scope;
  final List<Provider>? provider;

  const Injectable({this.name = '', this.scope = Scope.factory, this.provider});
}


class Provider<T> {
  final Type? useClass;
  final Object? useValue;
  final T? Function()? usefactory;
  final List<Type> deps;

 const Provider(
      {this.useClass, this.useValue, this.usefactory, this.deps = const []});
}
```

#### This works fine:

[image]

#### But when I try to directly pass-in the function. I am getting a compile error:

Any idea what is happening?

[image]

> **Error:**
>
> ---
>
> Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions. (Documentation) 
>  Try making the argument a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the constructor.
>
> ---
>
> Invalid constant value.
>
> ---
>
> The argument type 'ServiceA' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ServiceA? Function()?'. (Documentation)
>
> ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to remove the brackets from **inject<ServiceA>()**. Just make it **inject<ServiceA>**.

**usefactory**-s type is a function, but in your case, you are passing **ServiceA** type data.